# Passing function to a decorator

Tags: python, function, decorator

I am dealing with a problem related to decorators. I want to pass a method with a condition defined in class "Condition" to a decorator. I tried to pass it with the self. command. However this gives the error: AttributeError: 'SomeFunc' object has no attribute 'condition', when I use the decorator. Is there a way to work around this problem? I have included a small part of the code below. Thanks in advance!

```
class Condition:
    def gridfunc(self, PlotFunc, *args, **kwargs):
       """decorator that takes in "condition()" to make a pass or not
       """
       def wrapper(self, legends = None, colors = None, *args, **kwargs):
            PlotFunc(self, legends, colors, x, y, Title, args, **kwargs) #Edit
            if args == len(self.Data)-1 and self.condition(legends, colors, x, y, Title): #Edit
                plt.xlabel(x)#Edit
                plt.ylabel(y)#Edit
                plt.title(Title)#Edit
                plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = [1.05, 1], loc = "upper left")#Edit
                plt.savefig(Title,  bbox_inches= "tight", dpi = 1000)#Edit
           
       return wrapper #Edited

    def condition(self, legends, colors):
        if legends != None or colors != None: 
            return True
```

Edit: I simplified the code in my initial question. I have now included the the decorated function. The data input is quite lengthy (around 300 lines of code), so that would be too long to post here.

```
class PlotVSM(VS.DataSelect, VS.Hysteresis):
    def __init__(self, kpoints_, Data_, m_):
        super().__init__(k = kpoints_, m = m_, Data = Data_)
    
    loopdecorator = LoopDecorator()   
    @loopdecorator.gridfunc
    def HighFieldPlot(self, legends = None, colors = None, x = None, y = None, Title = None, *args, **kwargs):
        
        args = int(args[0]) #Function returns a tuple, so it needs to be changed to int
        self.kpointsHigh(args)

        #High field plot
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(self.T_heat_high, self.M_heat_high,'-*', color = colors[int(2*args)],label = legends[int(2*args)])
        plt.plot(self.T_cool_high, self.M_cool_high, '-^', color = colors[int(2*args)],label = legends[int(2*args)])
```

Comment: Please update your question with code which uses your decorator.

Comment: Do you have an indentation problem in `def gridfunc()`? Should `return wrapper` be part of this function?

Comment: That indentation should not be there. I thikn that went wrong when I posted the question

Comment: If you want to implement your own decorator, you should use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)  This will keep the proper names and docstrings for the decorated function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see now. You have a conflict with the two `self` arguments.

I solved it like this:

```py
class Condition:
    def gridfunc(myself, PlotFunc, *args, **kwargs):
       """decorator that takes in "condition()" to make a pass or not
       """
       def wrapper(self, legends = None, colors = None, *args, **kwargs):
            PlotFunc(self, legends, colors, x, y, Title, args, **kwargs) #Edit
            if args == len(self.Data)-1 and myself.condition(legends, colors, x, y, Title): #Edit
                plt.xlabel(x)#Edit
                plt.ylabel(y)#Edit
                plt.title(Title)#Edit
                plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = [1.05, 1], loc = "upper left")#Edit
                plt.savefig(Title,  bbox_inches= "tight", dpi = 1000)#Edit
           
       return wrapper

    def condition(self, legends, colors):
        if legends != None or colors != None: 
            return True
```

There maybe a standard for this, but I used `myself` to mean the instance that the decorator belongs to.

Alternatively if it really is so that the methods in your `Condition` class don't actually use their own `self` parameters, then you could dispense with them and use `@staticmethod` in both cases.